# std::find() can't compile with gcc

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<int, 5> a = {1,2,3,4,5};

    auto it = find(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 3);
    cout << *it << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program goes well using VS 2015, but fails to compile using gcc. Is the code wrong?
The error message is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘find(std::array<int, 5ul>::const_iterator, std::array<int, 5ul>::const_iterator, int)’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to

```
#include <algorithm>
```

This is where [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) lives. It seems with MSVC you get it through some transitive include in `<iostream>` or `<array>`.

I'd also suggest qualifying the names of standard library components fully, such as `std::array` and `std::find`, rather than `using namespace std;`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) or [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std). It makes it clear you are trying to use the standard library `find`, rather than something else.

It is good practice to check that your `find` actually found something, before trying to print it. If you tried to `find` a value that isn't there, then printing it would cause [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/1171191), which is a Bad Thing.

```
auto it = std::find(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 3);
if ( a.cend() == it ) {
    std::cout << "Couldn't find value!\n";
    return 1;
}
std::cout << *it << '\n';
return 0;
```

---

I'm also not a big fan of `std::endl`. Did you know it writes a `'\n'` *and flushes the stream*? A lot of people don't realise it does 2 things, which makes the intent of your code a lot less clear. When I read it, I don't know if the person who wrote it really did want to flush the stream, or just didn't know `std::endl` does that. I prefer to just use

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

, or if you really do want to manually flush the stream (unlikely), be explicit about it:

```
std::cout << '\n' << std::flush;
```